# How to link external CSS resource with JSF h:outputStylesheet?

Tags: jsf, external-url, outputstylesheet

I was wondering if I can use `<h:outputStylesheet/>` to link CSS from an external resources. I want to link the Yahoo Grids. Using the following code, I got a `RES_NOT_FOUND`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:tcmt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/tcmt/component">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssgrids/grids-min.css" target="head" />
     </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can keep using plain HTML for that:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssgrids/grids-min.css" />
```

When you use the `<h:graphicImage/>` or `<h:outputStylesheet/>` or `<h:outputScript/>`, then the file needs to be inside the `/resources` folder of the web application itself. See also [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template) But if the file is not provided by the web application, then you should use plain HTML `<img/>` or `<link/>` or `<script></script>` for this.

Instead of plain HTML `<link/>` you can also download this `.css` and put in the `/resources` folder of the web application so that you can use `<h:outputStylesheet/>`.