# JSF2 add custom font to css stylesheet

Tags: css, jsf-2, font-face

i want to use external font [WebSymbols](http://www.justbenicestudio.com/studio/websymbols/)

and i placed it my stylesheet.css declaration

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
src: url('websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
}

.fakeImage {
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

My stylesheet.css located in META-INF/resources/css/stylesheet.css file. I put font files  (eot, svg, etc.) in the same directory - META-INF/resources/css. In header of my jsf page i put reference to this stylesheet:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="stylesheet.css" />
```

But instead of special symbols from font i got regular text. All other css styles are worked normally. Any idea how to use custom font?

Comment: yes, this described in oracle java ee 6 tutorial, cause i want reference, for example, to images from page, as <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:filelist.png']}" styleClass="popupPanelLink" />

Comment: Ok didn't know that. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *My stylesheet.css located in META-INF/resources/css/stylesheet.css file*

META-INF? So this is bundled in a JAR file which is in turn dropped in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Regardless, you need to use the `#{resource}` resolver instead to resolve classpath resources to proper `/javax.faces.resource` URLs .

```
src: url("#{resource['css:websymbols-regular-webfont.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['css:websymbols-regular-webfont.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
     url("#{resource['css:websymbols-regular-webfont.woff']}") format('woff'),
     url("#{resource['css:websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
     url("#{resource['css:websymbols-regular-webfont.svg']}#WebSymbolsRegular") format('svg');
```

Further, I recommend to put one additional path in `/resources` folder which can then represent the *real* library name. The `library="css"` is namely the wrong usage of the resource library. It should not represent specific resource types (CSS/JS/images) at all, but a real common library name. For example, `/common`. You can then reference the stylesheet and the resources as follows:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="common" name="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

and

```
src: url("#{resource['common:css/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['common:css/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
     url("#{resource['common:css/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff']}") format('woff'),
     url("#{resource['common:css/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
     url("#{resource['common:css/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg']}#WebSymbolsRegular") format('svg');
```

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)