# Import custom fonts to JSF

Tags: css, jsf, fonts

I can't import custom fonts into my JSF pages. Project structure looks like this:
[image: Project structure screenshot]

I've tried to write the following in my styles.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold";
    src: url('#{resource["fonts/GothaProBol.otf"]}');
}
```

But it doesn't work. It gets compiled to `/javax.faces.resource/fonts/GothaProBol.otf.xhtml`, but the font is not in `javax.faces.resource` and I have no idea why it appends `.xhtml`.

The following:

```
src: url("#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/fonts/GothaProBol.otf");
```

is compiled to

```
src: url("/resources/fonts/GothaProBol.otf");
```

but it doesn't work either.

How do I import the fonts properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar question here [JSF2 add custom font to css stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700341/jsf2-add-custom-font-to-css-stylesheet)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did this using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/):

1. Added the [dependency](http://mavenrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces) (`pom.xml`):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Added OmniFaces' resource handler to `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <resource-handler>
        org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler
    </resource-handler>
</application>
```

3. Mapped `/javax.faces.resource/*` to `FacesServlet` as follows (`web.xml`):

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

4. Used `#{resource["<path>"]}` in CSS, like so:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold";
    src: url('#{resource["fonts/GothaProBol.otf"]}');
}
```

Comment: I found I didnt need to use the <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This URL works

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src:
    url("mfont/mfont.ttf.xhtml?ln=fonts")
    format("truetype")
}
```

The file is situated in "/resources/fonts/mfont/mfont.ttf"

Also note that the  css file itself is included using h:outputStylesheet (because font urls need to be relative to css)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I solve it as following :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
    src: url('#{resource["fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"]}');
}
```