# JSF Resource and .xhtml extension

Tags: css, jsf, fonts, resources

I have a JSF project with vendor libraries inside the Resource folder.

When I do this,

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

.. it outpus

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/InternalWeb_war_exploded/javax.faces.resource/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.xhtml" />
```

... which works. But stuff referenced in the CSS such as web fonts does not load because it doesn't have the .xhtml suffix automatically added to it.

How should I best deal with this?

Comment: Maybe it's already answered for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700341/jsf2-add-custom-font-to-css-stylesheet

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen I already saw that answer previously. In his case, he was using his own stylesheet and could do that. In mine, I'm using a library and you don't just modify code in libraries to get it working!

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-3-2-1-from-webjars-org-with-jsf/

Comment: @BalusC No, because the question is slightly different and the answer in that question involved modifying the CSS file directly.

Comment: So you didn't read the answer from top to bottom?