# How to get handle to a resource within a JSF class?

Tags: jsf, properties, resources, classpath

I've put a properties file within `src/main/resources` in my JSF project.

How do I get a handle to it? I understand that EL doesn't work within a backing bean.

**Note:** The file is in `src/main/resources` - NOT `src/main/webapps/resources`, so the following doesn't work:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
File value = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{resource['resources:email.properties']}", File.class);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's thus in the classpath. You can just use [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an `InputStream` out of it. Assuming that `src` is the classpath root and that `main/resources` is the package:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("main/resources/foo.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(input);
// ...
```

Alternatively, if it's supposed to be specific to the webapp and thus isn't supposed to be overrideable by a file on the same path elsewhere in the classpath which has a higher classloading precedence (e.g. in appserver's lib or the JRE's lib), then use [`ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("main/resources/foo.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(input);
// ...
```

As to the `#{resource}` syntax, this is indeed specifically for CSS/JS/image resources placed in `/resources` folder of public web content. See also [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: Superb! Thanks once again BalusC.

Comment: I think I have something wrong with my TomCat 7 install - this is actually coming up with a Null Pointer Exception and was not working as I expected? I have tried a leading slash and this does not work either. My JSF application has the usual Maven archetype and the path to the file is src/main/resources/foo.properties

Comment: Oh, then I believe you need `getResourceAsStream("foo.properties")` instead. Or maybe `getResourceAsStream("resources/foo.properties")`. Depends on how Maven builds the WAR, I can't tell that from top of head as I don't use it. Just read Maven docs or extract the WAR and explore `/WEB-INF/classes` to learn the build structure. Leading slash should not be used in the thread's context classloader, it'll always return `null` then. It's optional in the webapp resource loader but using it would always expect it to be a public webcontent resource.

Comment: InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/foo.properties") worked. The example with FacesContext didn't. Thanks!

Comment: No? Well, that'll be something Mavenish. Anyway, you're welcome again :)