# Finding path to JSF resource

Tags: java, jsf, resources, java-server

I am working on a JSF website and I need some help. I have an XML file that I am trying to read from by backing bean but I don't know how to find the path to it. It is in my resources folder (resources/movies.xml). How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590003/jsf-how-to-get-handle-to-a-resource-within-a-backing-bean

Answer (score 8):

If it is indeed the `/resources` folder of the public web content where you usually store the static web resources like CSS/JS/images, then you can use `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()` to get an `InputStream` of it.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
InputStream input = externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/movies.xml");
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I get path of folder in webapp resources folder:

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String resHomeImgPath = servletContext.getRealPath("resources/img/home");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: getRealPath() is bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12160639 Use getResource()/getResourceAsStream() instead.