# Rerendering composite component by ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, composite-component

I have build a composite component witch looks something like this:

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="id" required="false" />
  <composite:attribute name="label" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}">
    <fieldset class="fieldset"><legend>${cc.attrs.label}</legend></fieldset>
  </h:panelGroup>  
</composite:implementation>
```

The compent displays the current label correctly.

```
<xyz:comp id="idMyComponent" label="#{someBean.text}"/>

...
<a4j:ajax ... render="idMyComponent" />
...
```

Now when the action is preformed nothing happens. However when I add a Postfix to the ID in the component it works fine (see below).

```
...
<composite:implementation>
      <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}Label">
...
```

And define the ID in render with the postfix:

```
<xyz:comp id="idMyComponent" label="#{someBean.text}"/>

...
<a4j:ajax ... render="idMyComponentLabel" />
...
```

Can some on explain to me why it only works when I add a postfix to the ID in `h:panelGroup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is actually two-fold.

The first problem is that the `<xyz:comp id>` actually specifies the ID of the composite component *itself*, the `<cc:implementation>`. This is by default nowhere represented in HTML output and therefore ajax/JavaScript can't locate it by `document.getElementById()` and friends.

Actually, your `<h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}">` ends up in generated HTML output as follows (rightclick page and *View Source* to see it yourself):

```
<span id="idMyComponent:idMyComponent">
```

The second "problem" is that RichFaces/Ajax4jsf has enhanced the referencing/finding of JSF components in the tree by relative client ID (i.e. not starting with `:`) by not only searching in the context of the current `NamingContainer`, but also in all other `NamingContainer` components. A composite component is inherently also a `NamingContainer` component.

Your first attempt failed because it found the composite itself instead of the panel group, but JS/ajax in turn failed to update because there doesn't exist any HTML element with `id="myComponent"` in the generated HTML output.

Your second attempt succeeded because it finally found the real panel group (note: because it also searched in all other `NamingContainer` components; this would still have failed if you've used `<f:ajax>` instead of `<a4j:ajax>`).

The right way to fix your problem is not using `#{cc.attrs.id}` on a JSF component, but using `#{cc.clientId}` on a plain HTML element.

```
<span id="#{cc.clientId}">
```

*(yes, use a `<span>` or `<div>` instead of `<h:panelGroup>` inside the `<cc:implementation>`)*

This way JSF can find the component by client ID (in order to generate the proper ajax response) **and** JS can find the HTML element by client ID (in order to update the right HTML element based on ajax response).

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/jsf-update-with-ajax-non-jsf-things)
- [Integrate JavaScript in JSF composite component, the clean way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615556/integrate-javascript-with-jsf-the-clean-way)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)