# Can I add a meta tag to a particular page that is using templates

Tags: jsf, tags, facelets, meta

I have a page that uses a template

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/facelets/templates/clientPage.xhtml">
```

I was hoping to only render the compatibility view for this particular page using the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

The tag does not work unless I add it to the root template page. Is there a way I can add it to specific pages that use the template.

Comment: This question is unclear. What kind of templates? Php, Ruby, Javascript, Smarty, Mustache? What kind of compabilty view, compabilty to what? What meta tag?

Comment: Its an html template. I am using JSF. I saw the answer to a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545210/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-header-when-using-template But is there a way to do this without any changes to the template page ?

Comment: Try to improve your question. Than you get better help.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an `<ui:insert>` in the master template at the desired location:

`clientPage.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...>
    ...
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="head-meta" />
        ...
    </h:head>
    ...
</html>
```

Extend the master template with another master template:

`i18ClientPage.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/facelets/templates/ie8ClientPage.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <ui:define name="head-meta">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Finally let those template clients use this master template instead.

Comment: Excellent BalusC!