# PrimeFaces CSS look'n'feel missing and JS "Uncaught Reference Error: PrimeFaces is not defined"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use Picklist from Primefaces. When the page is rendered, the javascript engine in Chrome cannot find Primefaces object. I get the following error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined'. Am I missing to include any resource (js) in my .xhtml file? Please advise. Thanks.

Xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="../jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css" media="all" />
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="../jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>
<h:body>
<form id="form_486588" class="appnitro" method="post">
            <div class="form_description"></div>
            <p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{editorsMB.editors}" var="editor"
                itemLabel="#{editor}" itemValue="#{editor}" />
            <p:commandButton id="citySubmit" value="Submit"
                style="margin-top:5px" />
        </form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Managed bean

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

@ManagedBean(name = "editorsMB")
@SessionScoped
public class AdminEditorsBean {

    private DualListModel<String> editors;  

    public AdminEditorsBean(){
    List<String> adminsSource = new ArrayList<String>();  
    List<String> adminsTarget = new ArrayList<String>();  

    adminsSource.add("aaa");  
    adminsTarget.add("target1");
    editors = new DualListModel<String>(adminsSource, adminsTarget);  
    }

    public DualListModel<String> getEditors() {  
        return editors;    
}  
    public void setEditors(DualListModel<String> editors) {  
        this.editors = editors;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: I encountered this issue using the PrimeFaces 10 dialog framework to open a simple facelets page in a popup dialog. In my case, the page inside the dialog was very simple and contained only a single `p:graphicImage` component. I was getting a "_$ is not defined_" error that went away when I added a _hidden_ `p:commandButton`. The error was caused by PrimeFaces' CSS/nonce code that needed jQuery, but couldn't find it.. When I tried to manually include jQuery, the error changed to "_PrimeFaces is not defined_" so I added the hidden `p:commandButton` and that made all the errors go away.

Answer (score 29):

PrimeFaces will auto-include the necessary JS/CSS resources in `<h:head>`.

However, you don't have that tag. You've there a "plain HTML" `<head>`. Fix it accordingly:

```
<html>
    <h:head>
        ...
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        ...
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This mistake should also have been logged in the server log as below:

> [One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940644/one-or-more-resources-has-the-target-of-head-but-not-head-component-has-been)

See also [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets) and [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) for various correct examples of authoring JSF/Facelets pages.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: PrimeFaces as being a jQuery based JSF component library already ships with jQuery and jQuery UI bundled. You  should remove the manually included scripts from your page to avoid conflicts. See also [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeError over all place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place).

Take immediately the opportunity to replace that verbose `<link>` by a `<h:outputStylesheet>`. See also [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)