# RichFaces 4.4.5.Final: rich:PanelMenu not rendered

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have simple dynamic web project in eclipse to run jsf 2 (mojarra 2.2.8) web application using richfaces 4.4.5.Final ui component library. I was particularly interested in *rich:panelMenu* tag. I copied a showcase from this link (http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu&skin=blueSky) and pasted to my environment (eclipse). After deploying a war file on tomcat server (version 6), I didn't get any exception however I only got plain text as following.

```
Group 1
Group 2 
Group 3
```

There is no skin, no upper or downward arrows to click on to expand/collpase.

I attach here three screenshots.

```
1) added required jars for my jsf project in eclipse
2) expected output of invoking rich:panelMenu
3) visual output of invoking menu.xhtml that contains copied rich:panelMenu example
```

I wonder I am missing external jars. As far as I know, I don't need to do any configuration on web.xml or faces-config.xml for richfaces 4.5.5.Final library. Please correct me I am wrong on that matter.

I wonder what I am doing wrong. I appreciate your advice and suggestion on this matter. Thank you!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[update]

I am not sure why I am keep getting plain HTML when richfaces component was rendered. I blame myself not richfaces UI component. I had used it many years ago and it had served me well. However I switched to primefaces ui component library after struggling with richfaces for a few days. After fixing many common issues people run into for implementing jsf 2 + ui component library, in the end it worked.

One thing I would like to share with others who may be interested on this matter, I got plain HTML at first time for implementing *primefaces panelMenu*. However when I used chrome's developer tools to see if there are any errors, sure enough there was. After reading following thread ([PrimeFaces CSS look'n'feel missing and JS "Uncaught Reference Error: PrimeFaces is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553417/uncaught-reference-error-primefaces-is-not-defined)) from stackoverflow, I was able to enable panelMenu just fine.

For *richfaces panelMenu*, no errors were detected.

I hope this statement does not discourage people from using richfaces. I believe that it is one of great open source UI component libraries. Hope I could figure it out someday why I was failed to implement it in my environment.

Comment: That's the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/30258304/1818198 that you asked last week, isn't it?

Comment: @Makhiel: YES Indeed.