# ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm currently working on a JSF Project and I decided to use Primefaces. But as I switched my Work-Enviroment, the Browser keeps throwing multiple "ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined".

Here's the beginning of the add.xhtml page im currently working on (I hope it's enough):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:r="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="search.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="template.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="add.css" />
</h:head>

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">


    <h:form id="form">
        <p>
            <r:outputLabel styleclass="label" value="Datum:"></r:outputLabel>
        </p>
        <p>
            <r:calendar id="in_datum" value="#{addController.date}">    </r:calendar>
        </p>
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by incorrect usage of templating. The duplicate explains everything you need to know about properly using `<ui:composition template>`, including that anything outside `<ui:define>` is **ignored**. The cause of the exact error message is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14553417. Nonetheless, in a future question, try to create a MCVE as per http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. You'll during the process usually already discover the cause of the problem all by yourself. When you do not understand the cause itself, just ask here.

Comment: It works, thank you very much.