# Primefaces Spinner tag is not displaying anything

Tags: primefaces

Added `xmlns:p=http://primefaces.org/ui` and when used  `<p:spinner id="basic" value="1" />`
It is not displayin anything. Any idea if there is anything I’ve missed? I’m using JSF 2 and I need to have a quantity spinner and I found this Primeface’s one. Is there any other option if it’s impossible for this to work?

Now when I use spinner tag only an input text appears, but in the putput html i see:

```
<span id="j_idt11:5:basic" class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-corner-all"><input id="j_idt11:5:basic_input" name="j_idt11:5:basic_input" class="ui-spinner-input ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" type="text"><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-c"></span></span></a><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span></span></a></span>
```

Comment: So, other PrimeFaces tags ARE displayed?

Comment: Actually no, tried  <p:commandButton value="Fatal" /> and nothing gets displayed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and improve your question (and title).

Comment: what do i need to provide more? I thought having more code would confuse who ever is reading it since this is the main issue and nothing else is related. I've never used prime faces by the way this is my first time

Comment: "code people can use to reproduce the problem"

Comment: I just saw primefaces cannot_find_facelet_taglib warning message in the line I added xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"/>. is there any jar i need to add? looks like something is missing

Comment: Please read the setup section of https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf

Comment: now it appears, but actually the spinner as a textfield, there should be two buttons to increment and decrement but they are not appearing

Comment: @JasperdeVries updated the question

Comment: Then debug more? 404's for the css? js?

Comment: in browser's consloe i get about 10 lines of"ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined" error message

Comment: And what does the network tab show? 404's?

Comment: when i close the modal that has the spinner it give an error page that says :Page Not Found
Probably, your request is incorrect. Please check the request URL in the URL bar. with Url: https://www.javatpoint.com/primefaces-"MY site's url"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553417/primefaces-css-looknfeel-missing-and-js-uncaught-reference-error-primefaces

Comment: does this mean adding <h:head> would fix the issue?

Comment: I added h:head and h:body but it's still no working well

Comment: Thanks, added the tags in the tmp it works perfect