# PrimeFaces datepicker popup not showing

Tags: primefaces, datatable, datepicker, calendar

I have copy-pasted the Datepicker example (html + bean) from PrimeFaces showcase (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datePicker.xhtml), BUT the popup does not show on my application for any of the examples (it shows ok at showcase, so it's not a browser problem).

clicking on p:calendar gives this error : 
 [image]

now, clicking/refreshing around like a madman I somehow managed to get the popups showing...but I found these errors in console :

[image]

Do you have any ideas what is going on? Thank you.

Edit1 :

I'm trying to make a date range filter in PrimeFaces p:dataTable using p:datePicker widget. 
The problem is - the datePicker popup is hidden behind p:dataTable rows.

[image]

source code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<p:outputPanel id="test1">
    <p:dataTable value="#{myOrdersBean.addresses}" var="address"
                 widgetVar="addressTable" filteredValue="#{myOrdersBean.filteredAddresses}">

        <p:column headerText="Pickup time" sortBy="#{address.pickupTime}"
                  filterBy="#{address.pickupTime}" filterFunction="#{myOrdersBean.filterByDate}">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:datePicker selectionMode="range" value="#{myOrdersBean.pickupDateRange}"
                              readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" onchange="PF('addressTable').filter()"/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:outputLabel value="#{address.pickupTime}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:outputPanel>
</html>
```

Question #1: How do I display Datepicker reliably?

Question #2: How do I show the Datepicker popup in front of the Datatable rows?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `appendTo="@(body)"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces CSS look'n'feel missing and JS "Uncaught Reference Error: PrimeFaces is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553417/primefaces-css-looknfeel-missing-and-js-uncaught-reference-error-primefaces)

Answer (score 0):

1. the JQuery errors and datepicker not showing was because my `<head>` element did not contain datepicker.js.jsf resource

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/datepicker/datepicker.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=7.0"/>
```

2. the datepicker overlay was fixed by adding `appendTo="@(body)"`

thank you!