# Stylesheet file not found by <h:outputStylesheet>

Tags: css, jsf-2

Trying to include stylesheet in JSF2 using below tag

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/test.css"  />
```

However it's not picking and the directory structure of the stylesheet as follows

> WebContent-->css-->test.css

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 11):

The `<h:outputStylesheet>` (and `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>`) refers JSF resources from the special `/resources` subfolder. Just create that subfolder and put your `css/test.css` in there.

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- css
 |         `-- test.css
 :
```

Then you can keep using

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/test.css"  />
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727)