# Java web application cascade style sheets: where do I put them?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, resources

I'm writing a Java web application using JSF and Primefaces. I have to load a cascade style sheet named general.css and then I have the following line in my HTML head section:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="general.css"/>
```

This tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girgm.html) says I should put this file under web/resources/css, but when I do that the page is rendered with the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
```

Some suggestion about where should I put this file?

The question indicated as a possible duplicate does NOtT answer how to use the library element. Ir certainly indicates how to locate the need files inside the project structure, but I still would like to know how to use the library="css" element without needing to give the directory css/ every time I need to include a cascade style sheet file.

Comment: Just to be sure... The CSS file is in the file path web/resources/css ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But even so it won't load and I still get the error message.

Comment: Try to be more specific on the file path, maybe give the entire file path?

Comment: You mean an absolute path?

Comment: I may use an absolute path indeed. But this violates completely the idea of using the outputStylesheet thing, don't you think?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728304/stylesheet-file-not-found-by-houtputstylesheet

Comment: It sure helps! Thanks! And this question also suggested me another good one linked there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: Good. Submit an answer to this question explaining in detail how you solved your issue, thus providing a resource for anyone else with the same problem in the future. :)

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks once more!

Comment: You solved it yourself! No need to thank me!

Comment: I strongly disagree! You led me to the right answer, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue according with a suggestion by @BuddistBeast, removing the library="css" element.

It seems the idea of the library element is not organizing the directory structure under web/resouces, according with [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)