# Dropdown class not working in JSF

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf, drop-down-menu

I'm using Zurb-Foundation to design my web's front-end, using the CSS and JS libraries provided. I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1 as my IDE. When I run the project, I get to see the design properly, but not some actions, like the "dropdown".

The template I'm using is [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/store.html). I posted it as a link because I don't want to mess up with the code here if I'm using the same one.

I'm using JSF as my framework, just in case that is needed to know.

My references are as follows:

```
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
<title>Something</title>
</h:head>
```

What could possibly be wrong? Is it related to netbeans? Or there is a problem with the CSS / JS with JSF? Because I can see the dropdowns in my browser when I check the template at the Foundation webpage.

Comment: Do you see it when you check your local page in your standard browser? How do you build the menu? Using standard HTML? You should visit the page in your browser and check the sourcecode to see the difference to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake among starters is that they think that paths specified in `<link>` and `<script>` resources represent local disk file system paths relative to the web project folder structure. This is however wrong. They represent concrete URLs relative to the request URL as the enduser sees in browser's address bar. It's namely ultimately the webbrowser who has to download those CSS/JS resources individually, not the webserver who has got to include them in the HTML output somehow.

Also, you should be utilizing the JSF resource handling facility with components like `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>`. Given the following web project folder structure,

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    |-- general
 |    |    `-- css
 |    |         |-- foundation.css
 |    |         `-- normalize.css
 |    `-- vendor
 |         `-- js
 |              `-- custom.modernizr.js
 |-- page.xhtml
 :
```

this should do:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="general" name="css/normalize.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="general" name="css/foundation.css" />
<h:outputScript library="vendor" name="js/custom.modernizr.js" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)