# CSS not applying in JSF application

Tags: css, jsf

I am new to JSF. I am trying to put my inline styles to a CSS file but it is not working. Please find the code below.

My XHTML file is in following location:
`\WebContent\template\`

CSS is in following location:
`\WebContent\resources\css\`

XHTML code:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
       dfdskdksdk <h:outputText value="#{msg['message.test1']}" />
<table width="80%">
    <tr>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/style.css" />
        <td width="15%" background="red" >
            <b>Location Coverage*</b>
        </td>
```

I have tried using the following combinations

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="/resources/css/style.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="resources/css/style.css" />
```

Tried using this line inside and outside `<ui:composition>` tag.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using simple link with `#{request.contextPath}` like so `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
   href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is the placement of the `<h:outputStylesheet>`:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
    <ui:define name="content">
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When creating a template client, it's important to understand that anything outside `<ui:define>` is **ignored** (like as anything outside `<ui:composition>`).

Move the `<h:outputStylesheet>` declaration to inside `<ui:define>`:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

By the way, the way how you used the generic content type "css" as library name is awkward. As you don't seem to have a real library, just omit it altogether:

```
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: Hi baluSC thanks for replay but i have places everything as suggested by use its not working:(

Comment: here is my code in detail \JSFFaceletsTutorial\WebContent\template\Login.xhtml                        <ui:composition template="/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
       dfdskdksdk <h:outputText value="#{msg['message.test1']}" />
<table width="80%">
 <tr>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
  <td width="15%" class="tablewidth">
   <b>Location Coverage*</b>
  </td>

Comment: What does the generated HTML output say as to the `<link href>` value and what does the HTTP traffic monitor say as to response status/body of downloading the `css/style.css` file?