# Bootsfaces page shows up in browser without any styling

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I have created a simple JSF project in eclipse running on Tomcat, I tried including the Bootsfaces jar in /WEB-INF/lib and including the tags in my xhtml page (as shown in the Bootsfaces getting started page) ,but that does not seem to be work, I simply get the text without any styling.

Comment: You're not showing any code or sample of how the output looks. How is anyone supposed to be able to help?

Comment: Maybe it's because your page has `head` tag instead of `h:head` or `body` instead of `h:body`. I remember having some issue like that (not with Bootsfaces though) and corrected it by using the JSF tag.

Answer (score 2):

We've had a lot of trouble with this. I suspect it was the fault of the HeadRenderer in former BootsFaces versions. We've replaced the offending class by a different solution in BootsFaces 0.6.5.

If the problem still persists, try this:

1. Make sure you've added a `<h:head></h:head>` tag (even if it's empty). Do not use the HTML tag (`<head />`).
2. Check the URL pattern of the web.xml. Many tutorial recommend to put the JSF files into a virtual folder, such as `<url-pattern>/pages/</url-pattern>` . Don't do that. There's nothing wrong with simple patterns like ```*.jsf. By the way, this is the default, so you can safely omit the url-pattern altogether.
3. If that fails, add the `CombinedResourceHandler`  of OmniFaces or the `UnmappedResourceHandler` of BootsFaces. (As far as I know, that's almost the same implementation as its OmniFaces counterpart, so you can use the OmniFaces version as well - but I didn't test it).
4. Check the URL in your browser. Maybe you entered `localhost:8080/index.xthml` instead of `localhost:8080/index.jsf`?
5. If you're still stuck, open an issue on the BootsFaces GitHub repository (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues). But first read https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/157 - maybe that already solves your problem.