# Can't get Omnifaces resource handlers to work: Unable to find resource

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I've tried both `org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler` and `org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler`. It must be some misconfiguration, but I can't find what's wrong:

`faces-config-xml`:

```
<faces-config ...>
  <application>
  ....
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
  ...
```

`web.xml`:

```
<web-app ...>

...

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
      ionicons:ionicons.min.css=http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

...
```

Then on my jsf page:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="ionicons.min.css" library="ionicons" />
```

I get no runtime warnings or errors appart from the "Resource not found" error:

```
Unable to find resource ionicons, ionicons.min.css
```

I am using mojarra 2.2.5 and tomcat 6.0.41. I've tried both omnifaces 1.7 and 1.10 (my project also uses primefaces, but I don't know if that's relevant). Any ideas on how to find what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnmappedResourceHandler` doesn't support resource libraries. It's mentioned in the [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/UnmappedResourceHandler.html) and [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler).

> And the following CSS file reference (**note: the library is not supported by the UnmappedResourceHandler! this is a technical limitation, just exclusively use name**):
>
> ```
> <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
> ```

The technical limitation is that it's otherwise not possible to relatively reference resources from inside the CSS file. When using libraries, the path `/ionicons` would in your particular case be moved to query parameter `?ln=ionicons` and then the CSS file would be looking for relative image references in the wrong relative folder `/resources` instead of `/resources/ionicons`.

Just get rid of `library` by moving it into the `name`:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="ionicons/ionicons.min.css" />
```

```xml
<param-value>
  ionicons/ionicons.min.css=http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css
</param-value>
```

---

**Update**: after all, it appears that you actually don't need `CDNResourceHandler`. It is primarily designed to be able to move **auto-included** JSF resources such as `javax.faces:jsf.js` of standard JSF and `primefaces:jquery/jquery.js` of PrimeFaces to a CDN host. Standard JSF namely doesn't offer any possibility for this.

If you actually need to reference an external CSS or JS resource, just use plain `<link>` or `<script>` instead of `<h:outputStylesheet>` or `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.example.com/style.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.example.com/script.js"></script>
```

If you intend to template it so that you could [use `target="head"` of the usual JSF resource components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template), then declare a separate `<ui:insert>`. E.g. in master template

```
<h:head>
    ...
    <ui:insert name="head-resources" />
</h:head>
```

and in template client

```
<ui:define name="head-resources">
    ...
</ui:define>
```

Comment: I know about the unmapped resource handler. But is that the case for the CDN resource handler too? Because that's the one I set up on the example, or am I wrong and I have to avoid library on CDN handler too when the unmapped is also registered?

Comment: Alright, got it. And it's working now (Silly me, I don't know why I didn't try that before asking!) Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: The error came back, and this time I was able to trace it. I am not familiar with omnifaces' source code so I am probably wrong, but shouldn't this `== null` be `!= null`? https://github.com/elcodedocle/omnifaces/commit/76521b502e24e7d13acb8a0364fe963cf1d99196

Comment: Of course I was wrong about it and the code was ok! ^^' Only I was not realizing I needed a local copy of the CDN resource on my server in order for the wrapped resource handler to return a resource instead of null when calling its `createResource` method from `CDNResourceHandler.createResource` method.

Comment: If you don't want to have a local resource at all, just use plain HTML `<link>` instead. The `CDNResourceHandler` is primarily intented for delegating auto-included resources of e.g. JSF and PrimeFaces to a CDN host.