# Changing dynamically background color of commandbutton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to change color dynamically of `commandbutton` in Primefaces.

Here's code excerpt of commandbutton:

```
<p:commandButton id="movieBtn" value="#{kkcIncomingErrorBean.counter}" 
type="button" onclick="PF('errorTable').show()" 
styleClass="#{kkcIncomingErrorBean.buttonStyle}"/>
```

`buttonStyle` is field of `kkcIncomingErrorBean` class:

```
private String buttonStyle="background-color:red";
...
public String getButtonStyle() {
    return buttonStyle;
}

public void setButtonStyle(String buttonStyle) {
    this.buttonStyle = buttonStyle;
}
```

It is interesting that on update `counter` variable is updated but `buttonStyle` is not updated.

Do you have any ideas to fix this?

With regards

Comment: What is `styleClass="#{kkcIncomingErrorBean.buttonStyle}"`?

Comment: @Tiny, it is field in `kkcIncomingErrorBean` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `style` with `styleClass`.

The `style` attribute should be used to declare individual CSS properties like as you currently have tight-coupled in your model.

The `styleClass` attribute can only be used to declare CSS class names which are in turn declared in a normal CSS file with the properties. It ultimately renders as a HTML `class` attribute, which you should have noticed if you peeked around in JSF-generated HTML output.

So you've 2 options:

1. Use the `style` attribute.

   ```
   <p:commandButton ... style="#{kkcIncomingErrorBean.buttonStyle}" />
   ```
2. Use a CSS class name instead.

   ```
   private String buttonStyle = "error";
   ```

   with the below class declaration in a normal CSS file which you [include via `<h:outputStylesheet>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template).

   ```
   .error {
       background: red;
   }
   ```

   By the way, that setter is unnecessary.

Of course, a normal CSS class name as shown in option 2 is preferred. CSS properties doesn't belong in a Java file, but in a CSS file.

Comment: the css definition of .error cannot be in the jsf file ?

Comment: @Fred37b: yes you can do that, but this is a bad practice in HTML world.