# How to append javascript file to the body from javascript file which is in the same directory. Java server faces 2 JSF2

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, append

I have `test.js` file, it has an initialization function `window.onload = function initiliaze() { ... }`, which is invoked whenever the window is created.

I would like to include other javascript file "d3.min.js" , which is located in the same directory as `test.js` file is located, into the HTML body when `initiliaze()` is called.

This is how I include my javascript file into HTML body, from the same directory:

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "./d3.min.js";

document.body.appendChild(js);
```

however I still can't call `d3.min.js` functions, Firebug shows that d3 is not loaded.

Comment: Can you open the network inspector and see what happens to the d3.min.js request? What is the reply? Keep in mind that the path is relative to the URL of the page, not the URL of the script that creates it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do what normal people do, and use script tags ?

Comment: I opened Network inspector. This is what I get when I try to append d3.min.js to the body localhost:8080/myPage/pages/d3.min.js 404 not found

Comment: Possible  your path be worng

Comment: I use ./ to tell that it is in the same directory

Comment: js.src = "/d3.min.js"; try this and let me know.

Comment: Sounds more like a server setup issue. Something like missing mime-type for *.js or alike

Comment: `./` will target the directory where the html file is, not where the JS file using it is.

Comment: Same directory? Why bother then? Just write `js.src="d3.min.js"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adeneo suggested I removed my script inclusion code from initialization function and instead pasted this in *.jspx **header** (I'm using Java server faces) page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/script/d3.min.js"/>
```

Thanks to Halcyon, adeneo, Explore-X, Morten for helping me out.

Comment: `#{request.contextPath}` is shorter.

Comment: By the way, the formal way is just using `<h:outputScript>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8367421