# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined when PrimeFaces HeadRenderer is turned off in order to make JSF use its own HeadRenderer

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I had disabled PrimeFaces `HeadRenderer` for the reason as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32352869/1391249) in order to make the JSF implementation use its own `HeadRenderer` as follows.

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

This was working fine before PrimeFaces was upgraded. After upgrading PrimeFaces to 6.0 (along with "PrimeFaces Extensions" with the same version), inclusion of JavaScript files leads to some problems like.

```javascript
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

This error comes from within the PrimeFaces `core.js` file. Unlike previous versions, there is no `primefaces.js` but it was replaced by `core.js` and `components.js`.

Because of this error, AJAX calls doing paging, sorting, filtering in `<p:dataTable>`, for example, all stopped working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thats not really surprising. If PrimeFaces needs some headers for its work or lets the header rendering prepare some tasks and you disable it, there maybe something missing.

Comment: If you used the default head renderer, did you include primefaces.js manually? If so (and I assume you already tried since you are not new to all this, but I'll state it never the less) did you try adding both new js files? With what results? Or was it not needed to include something manually?

Comment: @Kukeltje : `primefaces.js` was not required to be added manually nor `core.js` and `components.js` are required to be added manually in the newer version of PrimeFaces. They are visible in the rendered HTML on the browser.

Comment: So these are loaded, but something else is not? Is that the observation?

Comment: @Kukeltje : Everything is loaded but perhaps, the order of included files is not correct but this is not a conclusion. I see files being included in the same order with or without PrimeFaces `HeadRenderer`.