# Integrating third party Bootstrap CSS themes with Bootsfaces

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3, themes, bootsfaces

I seem to have reached a conundrum in integrating this third party [Bootstrap theme](https://github.com/tui2tone/flat-admin-bootstrap-templates) within bootsfaces. Currently what I'm trying to do is include the css/js files within the xhtml files, but that doesn't seem to display any styling or show any references to the css files when inspecting the page. Will I need to build bootsfaces from source? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question is overly vague. Please describe the technical problem in detail. Do you mean to say that when you use a `<link>` or `<h:outputStylesheet>` referencing that theme CSS file, that you don't see it to show up in the generated HTML output when inspecting it in the webbrowser?

Comment: Yes, I do not see references to the theme css files when I use `<link>` or `<h:outputStylesheet/>`

Comment: Apparently your way of authoring the JSF/Facelets template is wrong. E.g. you placed them *outside* a `<ui:composition>` or `<ui:define>` instead of inside which causes them to be plain ignored. Hard to answer without seeing your concrete problem in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) flavor. Perhaps this is already applicable as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4792862 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/8367421. At least, working through a basic JSF/Facelets tutorial wouldn't be a bad idea after all. It must enable you to explain and even demonstrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: Would you mind to add some source code to your question? This would help us to locate the bug. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I had put the css and js inputs in the wrong area

Answer (score 0):

Starting with BootsFaces 0.8.0, we (the BootsFaces team) have added full-blown theme support. This include the default theme, 16 Bootswatch themes which are included in the library, and arbitrary custom themes. Read the details [on our showcase](http://www.bootsfaces.net/layout/themes.jsf).

However, in earlier versions (i.e. BootsFaces 0.7.0 and below) it was a bit more difficult to get custom or third-party themes up and running. Therefore, I recommend updating to BootsFaces 0.8.x, if you're still using an older version.

<strike>**Update Dec 6, 2015**: Forget about my former answer. BootsFaces theming works a bit different than I thought. We've changed it in the soon-to-come BootsFaces 0.8.0, anyways. I'll update my answer as soon as I'll have worked out the details.</strike>

<strike>The default Bootstrap theme of BootsFaces is a simple file (bsf.css). If you don't activate it in the `web.xml`, BootsFaces runs without any theme. So your approach should work: simply add the CSS file to your XHTML page, and you're good to go. You don't have to compile BootsFaces from source.</strike>

Comment: Is there a way to integrate various Bootstrap themes into BootsFaces, besides the Bootswatch themes?