# Where is #{resource} EL specified?

Tags: jsf, resources, el, specifications

In a JSF page, I use EL to locate an image which placed in `/resource/images/` folder.

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:logo.gif']}"
```

How can EL locate the image?
Maybe a specification defines the rule, but I don't know which specification.
I try to find it in the [JSR-000344 JavaServer Faces 2.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344) ，the [JSR-000342 Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342), the [JSR-000341 Expression Language 3.0](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341), but not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [JSF 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec/jsf-2_0-fr-spec.pdf), it's first mentioned in chapter 2.6.2:

> ## 2.6.2 Rendering Resources
>
> Resources such as images, stylesheets and scripts use the resource handling mechanism as outlined in *Section 2.6.1
>   “Packaging Resources”*. So, for example:
>
> ```
> <h:graphicImage name=”Planets.gif” library=”images”/>
> <h:graphicImage value=”#{resource[‘images:Planets.gif’]}”/>
> ```
>
> These entries render exactly the same markup. In addition to using the `name` and `library` attributes, stylesheet and
>   script resources can be “relocated” to other parts of the view. For example, we could specify that a script resource be
>   rendered within an HTML “head”, “body” or “form” element in the page.

and then in chapter 5.6.2.5:

> ## 5.6.2.5 Resource ELResolver
>
> This resolver is a means by which `Resource` instances are encoded into a faces request such that a subsequent faces
>   resource request from the browser can be satisfied using the ResourceHandler as described in *Section 2.6 “Resource
>   Handling”*.
>
> #### ELResolver method implementation requirements
>
> If base and property are not null, and base is an
>   instance of `ResourceHandler` (as will be the case
>   with an expression such as `#{resource[‘ajax.js’]}`,
>   perform the following. (Note: This is possible due
>   to the `ImplicitObjectELResolver` returning the
>   `ResourceHandler`, see *Section 5.6.2.1 “Implicit
>   Object ELResolver for Facelets and Programmatic
>   Access”*)
>
> - If property does not contain a colon
>     character ‘:’, treat property as the
>     `resourceName` and pass property to
>     `ResourceHandler.createResource(resourceName)`.
> - If property contains a single colon
>     character ‘:’, treat the content before the ‘:’ as
>     the `libraryName` and the content after the ‘:’
>     as the `resourceName` and pass both to
>     `ResourceHandler.createResource(resourceName, libraryName)`
> - If property contains more than one colon
>     character ‘:’, throw a localized
>     `ELException`, including property.
>
> If one of the above steps results in the creation
>   of a non-null `Resource` instance, call
>   `ELContext.setPropertyResolved(true)` and return the
>   result of calling the `getRequestPath()` method on
>   the `Resource` instance.

It's also mentioned in same chapters in JSF 2.1 and 2.2 specification.

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, `images` is a really bad example of a resource library name. Don't take over that from the spec example.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template/)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/)