# Template jsf2.2 can't see css / I have tried every way

Tags: css, netbeans, jsf-2.2

I've created sample for JSF template. I did new file... Faceletes Template and CSS file is created by NetBeans itself. However when I try run my project there is normal text

> Top
>
> Content

and that's it. Semms like isn't connected with CSS...?

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="default.css" library="css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="cssLayout.css" library="css"/>
    <title>Facelets Template</title>
</h:head>
```

What is interesting when I do change in web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/template.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And welcome file is template.xhtml instead of index.html it works well but client page when I would use my template still is doesn't read css

```
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
```

I really have read much info but I can't find solution. I have done everything form [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template?lq=1) and my project still does not work.

My env: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
Java EE 7
GlassFish 4.1
JSF 2.2

Comment: Stop generating code. Instead, write code yourself. Do so as long as until you understand every single line/aspect of autogenerated code. The link you found clearly says to declare css in <ui:define> not <h:head> when using templating. The new duplicate link shows how to properly create/use templates themselves. If you still stucks, post a MCVE, not some incomplete code which makes the question very ambiguous.

Comment: Solved. The problem was in the path. localhost:8080/WebApplication/clinetpage.xhtml wasn't proper because only <html> tags Firefox shows. The proper path is localhost:8080/WebApplication/faces/clientpage.xhtml as file web.xml says. This was the solution.