# <h:outputstylesheet > doesn't work

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I am working on a migration project from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.2, I followed correctly the steps to do this migration but when I want to change the old tag  to import css files by the new tag ,this later doesn't work and any css files imported!!
pliz help and thx in advance!

```
<h:head><h:outputstylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/></h:hea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag is

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
```

With capital S, Probably a typo ;)

Btw i prefer to use pure html to import css no need to use a tag library for that

Comment: thx bro but it's in my code I wrote it with Capital S ;) ,and also I tried pure html and it doesn't work .

Comment: Have you tryed to use something like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   href="resources/css/test.css" media="screen" />  ?

Comment: yes I tried exactly what u told and still doesn't work!!

Comment: At this point I don't know how to help you without seeing the project structure. Is it somewhere on a public repo?

Comment: the wired thing is when I look the page from the visual source window my css work correctly but when I run the  application in server it's still not working :S

Comment: If you inspect the html with chrome and refresh do you see any errors in console?

Comment: yes I got errors like:    failed to load ressource:the server responded with a status of 404(Not http://localhos:8080/css/style.css Found )

Comment: Ok,  you are packaging a War application? If it is the case where are your css files?

Comment: yes,the css files were located in webapp/css folder

Comment: So if the 404 error you posted is right the app is searching the css without the context root

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template   it could be a jsf specification

Comment: yeah, I see thanks a lot bro,do  have any idea howa i can fix that!!