# Loading js and css files without specifying them in jsf files

Tags: javascript, css, jsf

is it possible to load JS and CSS files in JSF pages without mentioning them using `<link>` or `<script>`.

I want to dynamically load the css and js, so that I can avoid writing so much code.

Comment: jQuery has a [`getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method specifically to do this; you could [read its source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.getScript) and use a similar technique. I believe it basically loads a `.js` file using AJAX and `eval()` it immediately.

Comment: That said, you'd definitely be writing MORE code by loading these files dynamically than if you simply linked to them in the JSF file.

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8367421

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger and BalusC.