# Can I use expression language in style sheets with JSF?

Tags: css, jsf, el

I have a web site with a header on the top  and a menu on the left.
Every time I click on element of the menu it links to an anchor, but the (classic) problem is that the anchor is below the header.
I want to change the CSS of the anchors but the id of each element is dynamic.

Here's my anchor

```
<div id="#{name}"></div>
```

Here's my not working CSS:

```
<style>
##{name}{
my css...

}
</style>
```

How can I apply my CSS to the div "#{name}"  ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template

Comment: ... but, wait, why does your CSS needs to be dynamic? Can't you just include all the names there?

Comment: don't use id' s here use class