# JSF - Images & Icons Folder missing in resources

Tags: jsf

I have got the Problem that I can't access the images folder in my resources.

After deploying the project I see in Chrome that CSS files are included in `javax.faces.resources` but images and icons folders are missing.

How can I solve this problem?

This is my project structure

[image]

Facet Settings

[image]

Artifact Settings

[image]

In Chrome, you can see only the CSS folder...

Chrome View

[image]

Comment: Hi, JSF is in no way responsible for the deployment. Maven or your IDE is. Check those

Comment: Hi, I posted a Screenshot from my IDE, where I specified the Web Resources Directory Path, is this not enough for JSF? Do I need to specify it in Maven too?

Comment: Jsf cares about runtime locations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template where and how you put these development time and package them is not so,ethimg jsf cares about...

Comment: I found the Problem, the css files didn't access to images correctly.. the path was like '../images/..' i changed it too "#{resource['images/..']}" now it works