# Downloaded PDF from server is invalid although original is valid

Tags: java, pdf, omnifaces

I am using Omnifaces to create a pdf download button and get a pdf from the server. The downloaded pdf has blank pages and after using a pdf validator I am getting this errors:

> Validating file "manual(6).pdf" for conformance level pdf1.7
>
> The 'xref' keyword was not found or the xref table is malformed.
>
> The file trailer dictionary is missing or invalid.
>
> The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
>
> Error in Flate stream: data error.
>
> The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
>
> The document does not conform to the requested standard.
>
> The file format (header, trailer, objects, xref, streams) is
>   corrupted.
>
> The document does not conform to the PDF 1.7 standard.
>
> Done.

My code works for other pdf files.

This is my code:

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileDownloadView {

    private static final String FILENAME = "manual.pdf";

    public void download() throws IOException {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(FILENAME);
        File file = resource.getFile();
        Faces.sendFile(file, true);
    }

}
```

and the xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{fileDownloadView.download}" value="download" ajax="false">
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**The original pdf file scanned by the pdf validator return no errors.
The pdf after downloaded returns the above errors.**

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Norepro. At least not on a completely blank project with only the absolute minimum necessary libraries/configuration for the purpose. First thing to check is if there are in your actual project any servlet filters which manupulate the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to provide a static file for dowload is to use the builtin resources system of JSF: [See this Q/A for background.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

For example place the Primefaces 6.2 Documentation into the `/src/main/webapp/resources` folder (note this is **NOT** the same as `/src/main/resources` in my other suggestion above!) so you have a file:

```
/src/main/webapp/resources/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf
```

In your web project. Now in your faces simply add a static outputLink to this file:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{resource['primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf']}" >Download PF 6.2 Documentation!</h:outputLink>
```

That's it. The file will be served as is and the outputLink aktually provides a bookmarkable reference to the file.

This would btw. also circumvent the maven filtering issue as /src/main/webapp/resources normally should not be filtered.

*Why two answers? Knowing I could have edited the first answer to include both suggestions, I'd like to know which one is accepted if any.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

As [your comment in a followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439864/downloading-resources-using-jsf?noredirect=1#comment95689437_54439864) suggests that maven corrupts your PDF during build of the .war archive, I'd suggest you have to disable maven resource filtering during build for PDF files in your POM.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.pdf</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>*.pdf</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```