# JSF render contents of attribute dynamically

Tags: jsf

How can I render the contents of an attribute dynamically?

Something like:

```
style="#{not empty book.image ? 'background-image: url('+ book.image +'); border: 1px; ' : ''}
```

I don't know how to reference `book.image` inside the attribute.

I can't place a `ui:fragment` inside the element either to say whether to render or not `style`. I don't think it is an efficient idea to duplicate the whole element, which already has some other attributes, inside two different `ui:fragment`s (one with `empty rendered` and the other one with `not empty rendered`). I don't think it is a good idea to place my presentation in the `Named` bean like this: `style="#{bookNamedBean.TheStyle}"`, as it will mix layers.

Comment: Did you try `resource[book.image]` when `book.image` is something like `/path/to/some/image.jpeg`? See [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: I haven't. I am not using resources. This is a dynamic value I got from another system, not sure this apply to my situation

Comment: What is the problem with your suggested solution? It should work.

Comment: @Selaron It was failing with a numeric exception. The solution was pointed by honourable BalusC