# How can I integrate Tailwind CSS v3.0 into JSF project?

Tags: css, jsf, tailwind-css

I have a JSF project I want to use tailwind into it
Could anyone has idea how implement tailwind CSS into JSF

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

I have tried to implement but I couldn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: Which results in a CSS to load in your template

Comment: No, It is not just CSS file Tailwind v3.0 has a different configuration 
tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss
 I have tried to implement but I couldn't

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn
When I use is working fine but when I try use form template of tailwind doesn't work because it needs configuration in tailwind.config.js

Comment: You might want to have a look at PrimeFlex in combination with PrimeFaces

Comment: OK I will check it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using tailwind with postcss, and didn't get it to work. It was a lot of issues with getting the postcss processor to run. Using the tailwind cli went like a charm, however. The step are as follows:

1. Run npm init in the webapp folder (where the xhtml files reside)
2. Install tailwindcss as a dev dependency using npm
3. Follow the tailwind [getting started guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) for tailwind css
4. Finally, create a npm script for running tailwind css generation `"css-watch": "tailwindcss -i ./main.css -o ./dist/styles.css --watch"`
5. Start the css-watch script using `npm run css-watch`

Then, you probably want to do some hiding of the irrelevant files when you package the app. This is not necessary, but might be a requirement security-wise.