# Determine if JSF request is user initiated and ignore static content requests

Tags: jsf

I want to log all user JSF requests (including AJAX), to do this I have implemented an @Observer for the @RequestScoped

This works however it also fires for all static content GET requests including CSS/JS/Images etc. which I do not want to log.

Is there a convenient way to determine if the request was initiated from the user and ignore static file GET's? I thought of checking the requested files extension but some of the static files seem to end with .xhtml so that won't work

I am using Omnifaces if that helps (JSF 2.3 / CDI)

```
public void logRequest(@Observes @Initialized(RequestScoped.class) ServletRequest payload) {
    // logging request here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you're handling **all** resources via the [therefor provided JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template) such as `<h:outputScript>`, `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:graphicImage>`, then simply check if the request path starts with [`ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/application/resourcehandler#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER).

```java
public void logRequest(@Observes @Initialized(RequestScoped.class) ServletRequest payload) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) payload;

    if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER + "/")) {
        return; // It's a JSF resource request.
    }

    // Log request here.
}
```

> I am using Omnifaces if that helps (JSF 2.3 / CDI)

Yes, that definitely helps. There's since OmniFaces version 2.0 already a helper method which does exactly that, hereby reducing the boilerplate. It's the [`Servlets#isFacesResourceRequest()`](https://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Servlets.html#isFacesResourceRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-):

```java
public void logRequest(@Observes @Initialized(RequestScoped.class) ServletRequest payload) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) payload;

    if (Servlets.isFacesResourceRequest(request)) {
        return; // It's a JSF resource request.
    }

    // Log request here.
}
```

Comment: I do have some other servlets (JAWR CSS and JS) that handle requests but its trivial to extend your solution to include them too...thanks