# Adding third party CSS to my project dynamically

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to add an external third party stylesheet to my JSF project. The link to the site hosting the CSS is going to be set inside a database and I need to read the CSS location and apply the styles to my project. How would someone go about doing that?

I tried hosting my CSS on another webpage first to see if I can fetch it with

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://websitewithcss.com/style.css">
```

but that doesnt seem to be working inside of <h:head> and it just breaks the whole site.

I then tried using

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="https://websitewithcss.com/style.css">
```

but that doesnt seem to be working either.

Tnx for help in advance.

Comment: *"it just breaks the whole site"* you forgot to describe what exactly happens instead. It should work just fine. For example, did you get an exception? A good exception is the whole answer at its own and usually perfectly googleable. In case you're unable to interpret or google the exception, edit your question to include it. As to `<h:outputStylesheet>`, that indeed won't work for external resources at all. So forget that and use plain HTML `<link>` instead. In case you're interested, the purpose of `<h:outputStylesheet>` is explained in among others https://stackoverflow.com/q/8367421